# How to sync controller with Service

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, android-sqlite

I'm testing the communication of angular and SQLite. I need to get the ID and NAME of the selected company from database when the User access the page. I'm using the ion-autcomplete to select the company in the CRUD page.

Service: **sqlite.js**

---

```
(function () {


'use strict';

  angular
    .module('Test')
    .service('$sqliteService', $sqliteService);

  $sqliteService.$inject = ['$q', '$cordovaSQLite'];
  function $sqliteService($q, $cordovaSQLite) {

    var self = this;
    var _db;

    self.db = function () {
      if (!_db) {
        if (window.sqlitePlugin !== undefined) {
          _db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "my.db", location: 2, createFromLocation: 1 });
        } else {
          // For debugging in the browser
          _db = window.openDatabase("my.db", "1", "Database", 200000);
        }
      }
      return _db;
    };

    self.getFirstItem = function (query, parameters) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      self.executeSql(query, parameters).then(function (res) {

        if (res.rows.length > 0)
          return deferred.resolve(res.rows.item(0));
        else
          return deferred.reject("There aren't items matching");
      }, function (err) {
        return deferred.reject(err);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    };
  }
})();
```

Factory: **CompanyService.js**

```
(function () {


'use strict';

  angular
    .module('Test')
    .factory('CompanyService', CompanyService);

  CompanyService.$inject = ['$q', '$sqliteService'];
  function CompanyService($q, $sqliteService) {

    return {      
      getId: function (Id) {

        var query = "Select * FROM Company WHERE ID = ?";
        var values = [Id];

        return $q.when($sqliteService.getFirstItem(query, values));
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

Controller: **CompanyController.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('Test')
    .controller('CompanyEditController', CompanyEditController);

  CompanyEditController.$inject = ['$scope', '$q', '$stateParams', '$state', '$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaImagePicker', '$ionicPopup', 'CompanyService'];
  function OcorrenciaEditController($scope, $q, $stateParams , $state, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaImagePicker, $ionicPopup, CompanyService) {

    var vm = $scope;

    vm.modelToItemMethod = function (modelValue) {
      var d = $q.defer();
      CompanyService.getId(modelValue)
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log('My first promise succeeded', JSON.stringify(data));
          $q.resolve(data);
        }, function(error) {
          console.log('My first promise failed', error.message);
        });
      return d.promise;
    };
})();
```

Company.html

```
<input ion-autocomplete ng-model="company.IdCompany" type="text" name="fieldEmpresa" placeholder="Empresa" readonly="readonly" class="ion-autocomplete" autocomplete="off" max-selected-items="1" required
                 item-value-key="Id"
                 item-view-value-key="CompanyName"
                 items-method="getTestItems(query)"
                 cancel-label="Cancel"
                 items-removed-method="itemsRemoved()"
                 loader-icon="spinner"
                 external-model="company"
                 model-to-item-method="modelToItemMethod(modelValue)"/>
```

I don't undestand why I need to use de "$q.defer" inside the controller if i'm using inside de Factory and Service. If I don't use, controller can't return the value to ion-aucomplete. Am i missing something? Or the code is right?

Comment: You might be binding this method to auto complete. I'm assuming as you haven't shared that code. Instead of using $q.defer , you can just do return CompanyService.getId(modalValue); in your VM.modelToItemMethod

Comment: I added the autocomplete snippet to the question. I can only return the company to the autocomplete using the $q.defer in the code. If I remove the method is executed three times and it doesn't update the autocomplete.

Comment: Try just `return CompanyService.getId(modalValue); ` in your method

Comment: That's it. I lost some time looking for and the anwser was so simple. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding this method to auto complete; as ajax call is asynchronous, you gotta return a primise. Thats the reason why you ended up using $q.defer.

If you dont want to use $q, then instead of using $q.defer , you can just do `return CompanyService.getId(modalValue);` in your VM.modelToItemMethod which inturn returns a deferred object.